# Image clarity issue in HTML page

Tags: python, html, visualization, dpi, aspose.words

I have Matplotlib & Seaborn visualizations that need to be saved in HTML. Since there is no direct method to do so, I first saved the images in PNG & then converted them to HTML. This decreased the quality of my images.

My code:

```
import aspose.words as aw 
from PIL import Image

def pairplot_fun(eda_file, pairplot_inputs, pairplot_png, pairplot_html):
    pairplot_var=pairplot_inputs[0]
    sns.pairplot(eda_file, hue=pairplot_var, height=4);
    plt.savefig(pairplot_png) 
             
    doc = aw.Document()
    builder_pairplot = aw.DocumentBuilder(doc)
                    
    builder_pairplot.insert_image(pairplot_png)
    doc.save(pairplot_html, dpi=1200)
```

Specifying the 'dpi' this way isn't making any difference. How do I improve the clarity of my image saved in HTML format?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65245850/why-is-my-image-in-html-looks-blurry-even-tho-the-image-resolution-is-high

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify image resolution in Aspose.Words `HtmlSaveOptions` using [HtmlSaveOptions.image_resolution](https://reference.aspose.com/words/python-net/aspose.words.saving/htmlsaveoptions/image_resolution/) property.

```py
doc = aw.Document("in.docx")
options = aw.saving.HtmlSaveOptions()
options.image_resolution = 1200
doc.save("out.html", options)
```